# How can I effectively parse a Google Spreadsheet with data not aligned well within Columns and Rows?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I have a data export in a very inconvenient format. In sheet1, I have student grade data that I cannot figure out how to extract into sheet2, where I am attempting to separate and SUM grades in one column IF they are designated with HL or SL in another column. However, the student name sits in a set of merged cells one row above the data and separated by blank rows.

I believe it could be done with =FILTER and =QUERY, but these are not my strengths.

If you are willing to help:
[Please see the anonymized example of the aforementioned two sheets.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mTJy7dRxiItAX0e3MZunVf8KVolOAJI4y2BheNL-1Bw/edit#gid=0)

In sheet2 the desired data and a stab at the formulas can be found.

With great appreciation and apologies if I've left anything out.

Comment: Do all students study the same number of subjects? This will influence the approach required.

Comment: No, the subject number changes. I really should have noted that as it wrecked my initial plan of of counting off multiples. Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

##### Tag data with Student Name

In `sheet1`, insert a `helper column A` and add the following formula in `cell A7` and copied to rows below:

```
=if(B7<>"",if(B6="Advisor",B5,A6),"")
```

**Helper Column**
<kbd>[image]</kbd>

### Calculations

---

##### Named Ranges

*To make the formulas shorter in length and easier to follow, I used named the ranges.  You could alternatively use the A1 range addresses*

| Name | Range |
| --- | --- |
| helper | `Sheet1!A:A` |
| advisor | `Sheet1!B:B` |
| average | `Sheet1!K:K` |
| level | `Sheet1!G:G` |
| grade | `Sheet1!L:L` |
| beCols | `Sheet1!N:O` |
| names **<sup>*</sup>** | `Sheet2!A2:A` **<sup>*</sup>** *the filtered list on Sheet2* |

##### Formulas

| Multiple Formulas |
| --- |
| Sheet2!A2 - **Student** `SORT(UNIQUE(FILTER(helper,helper<>"")),1,1)` |
| Sheet2!B2 - **Advisor** `=BYROW(names, LAMBDA(x, IF(x<>"", INDEX(advisor,MATCH(x,helper, 0)),)))` |
| Sheet2!C2 - **HL Sum** `=BYROW(names, LAMBDA(x, IF(x<>"", SUMIFS(grade,helper,x,level,"HL"),)))` |
| Sheet2!D2 - **SL Sum** `=BYROW(names, LAMBDA(x, IF(x<>"", SUMIFS(grade,helper,x,level,"SL"),)))` |
| Sheet2!E2 - **BE Count** `=BYROW(names, LAMBDA(x, IF(x<>"", COUNTIF(filter(beCols, helper=x),"BE"),)))` |

Depending on what you want, you can combine all the formulas in a single formula.

##### Single Formula

```
In Sheet2!A2, place

     =BYROW(SORT(UNIQUE(FILTER(helper,helper<>"")),1,1),  
      LAMBDA(x, IF(x<>"", {
        INDEX(names,MATCH(x,names,0)), 
        INDEX(advisor,MATCH(x,helper,0)),
        SUMIFS(grade,helper,x,level,"HL"),
        SUMIFS(grade,helper,x,level,"SL"),
        COUNTIF(filter(beCols, helper=x),"BE")},)))
```

If you want to generate the column labels as well you can add them into the formula

```
={ "Student","Advisor","HL Sum","SL Sum","BE Count";
    [existing formula here] 
 }
```

### Images

---

**Single Formula w/ Labels**
<kbd>[image]</kbd>

**Student Formula**
<kbd>[image]</kbd>

**Advisor Formula**
<kbd>[image]</kbd>

**HL Formula**
<kbd>[image]</kbd>

**SL Formula**
<kbd>[image]</kbd>

**BE Formula**
<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Comment: This worked well to link the student name to each row of data. Thank you!

Comment: With the addition of the helper column, I was able to compose =QUERY('sheet1'!B5:Q2000,"select B, C, E, H, M, O, P where B is not null"), but still working on summing finals grades for HL independently of SL per student.

Comment: @ZacharyBlakley I updated the answer with sample formulas that use the helper column.  The example formulas are shown individually for each column, and I also showed you them combined in a single formula.

Answer (score 0):

Delete rows 1-4 at the top of Sheet1 and any blank rows at the bottom, then try the following in another sheet:

```
=lambda(oldtbls,header,lambda(students,lambda(newtbl,
{query(newtbl,"select Col1,Col2,sum(Col12) group by Col1,Col2 pivot Col7",1),{"BE";index(sort({unique(filter(students,students<>"")),ifna(vlookup(unique(filter(students,students<>"")),query(newtbl,"select Col1,count(Col1) where Col14='BE' or Col15='BE' group by Col1",1),2,0),0)}),,2)}})(
{{"Student",header};filter({students,oldtbls},students<>"")}))(
scan(,index(oldtbls,,1),lambda(a,r,iferror(if(offset(r,-1,0)="Advisor",offset(r,-2,0),if(r="",r,a)),)))))(
Sheet1!$A:$O,
Sheet1!$2:$2)
```

This should work if the number of subjects changes from student to student. I'm not going to try to explain all this, but in essence we are creating a flat table and then running the necessary queries from it.